# Extending Java Jackson ObjectNode and implement marker interface

Tags: java, interface, jackson

I want to create a custom POJO object that extends Jackson ObjectNode and implements an interface as follows:

```
public class MyClass extends ObjectNode
    implements
    MyInterface,
    java.io.Serializable {

   public MyClass(JsonNodeFactory nc) {
      super(nc);
      }
}
```

is that possible? I want the custom POJO to behave the same as ObjectNode. I only want to add to it a marker interface.

I am having the following exception when Jackson tries to deserialize an object composed of MyClass object.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem deserializing property 'request_data' (expected type: [simple type, class com.tutorial.MyClass]; actual type: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode`), problem: argument type mismatch
at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 157104] (through reference chain: com.tutorial.RequestDto["request_data"]->com.tutorial.ApiRequestData["request_data"])

Comment: Technically it should be possible but it might be hard to get Jackson to use your class instead of `ObjectNode`. What exactly do you need that marker interface for?

Comment: There is an existing API that creates an HTTP request body from POJOs that implements a specific marker interface.  There is a demand that I need to create an HTTP request body from the ObjectNode. Hence, I need to create a custom object that extends ObjectNode and implements the marker interface at the same time. But Jackson is throwing exception.

Comment: would be great to also state the exceptions you are facing

Comment: Do you actually need to return an `ObjectNode` or is the ask that you _convert_ it into whatever POJO is required? The latter would be way easier to achieve with Jackson and probably makes more sense.

Comment: I have edited my question and I have added the exception thrown. 
I want an object that extends ObjectNode and implements an interface either to add my own logic. Besides, I want the custom POJO to serve as Tree node as Object node.